# MIPS instruction timing and fixing hazard

Tags: mips

```
               |  1 |  2 |  3 |  4 |  5 |  6 |  7 |  8 |  9 | 10 | 11 |
ADD R1,R2,R3   | IF | ID | EX | MA | WB |    |    |    |    |    |    |
SUB R4,R1,R3   |    | IF | ID | EX | MA | WB |    |    |    |    |    |
AND R6,R1,R7   |    |    | IF | ID | EX | MA | WB |    |    |    |    |
OR  R8,R1,R9   |    |    |    | IF | ID | EX | MA | WB |    |    |    |
XOR R10,R1,R11 |    |    |    |    | IF | ID | EX | MA | WB |    |    |
```

So i understand that looking at this all subsequent instructions depend on R1 value being written. So to fix this, i need to insert stalls.

```
AFTER (Using Stalls)
               |  1 |  2 |  3 |  4 |  5 |  6 |  7 |  8 |  9 | 10 | 11 |
ADD R1,R2,R3   | IF | ID | EX | MA | WB |    |    |    |    |    |    |
SUB R4,R1,R3   |    | IF | ID | *  | *  | EX | MA | WB |    |    |    |   
AND R6,R1,R7   |    |    | IF | ID | EX | MA | WB |    |    |    |    |
OR  R8,R1,R9   |    |    |    | IF | ID | EX | MA | WB |    |    |    |  
XOR R10,R1,R11 |    |    |    |    | IF | ID | EX | MA | WB |    |    |
```

Does that work or do i need to insert another stall after the  Memory Access has occurred?

What would the timing look like if i used forwarding? How do i do that?

Comment: AFAICT, the stalls for `SUB` wouldn't start until later. It would _still_ do `IF` at `T2` as it doesn't even know that it needs a stall until after `ID` at `T3`. That is, the `SUB` should look like `- IF ID * * EX MA WB` as it is only `SUB`'s `EX` that must be stalled to `T6` (after `ADD`'s `WB` at `T5`). The `IF` and `ID` for the other instructions have no delays, so they start "on schedule" as well. If you agree, I'd revise the 2nd diagram before continuing the analysis.

Comment: I made the change you suggesting, i think. Is that what you are saying?

Comment: Close. Now repeat for the others. `IF` and `ID` don't stall, so they go in their regular place. Thus, `AND`'s `IF` is `T3` (_not_ `T5`) and so forth ...

Answer (score 0):

With stalls, the timing looks like:

```
               |  1 |  2 |  3 |  4 |  5 |  6 |  7 |  8 |  9 | 10 | 11 |
ADD R1,R2,R3   | IF | ID | EX | MA | WB |    |    |    |    |    |    |
SUB R4,R1,R3   |    | IF | ID | *  | *  | EX | MA | WB |    |    |    |
AND R6,R1,R7   |    |    | IF | ID | *  | EX | MA | WB |    |    |    |
OR  R8,R1,R9   |    |    |    | IF | ID | EX | MA | WB |    |    |    |
XOR R10,R1,R11 |    |    |    |    | IF | ID | EX | MA | WB |    |    |
```

This is because only the initial `ADD` writes to `R1`. And, there are no more overlaps between the destination registers of the instructions and the source registers of later instructions.

With forwarding, the output of `ADD` (i.e. `R1`) would be available *after* its `EX` phase at `T3` (i.e. it is available to any subsequent instruction at the start of `T4`)

So, even the most hard pressed instruction (the `SUB`) would have the value available for its `EX` phase at `T4` because of the forwarding.

So, with forwarding, the timing is the same as the initial diagram (i.e. forwarding fixes the hazard).